# Meteor: sharing variables between helpers

Tags: meteor

I am currently building a quizz app in Meteor and have three function within helpers

```js
Template.quizPage.helpers({
//this helper finds the currentquiz and returns the currentquestion to the template

 question: function(){
     currentquiz = this.quiztitle;
     currentQuestion = Session.get('currentQuestion') || 0;
     return Quizzes.findOne({'quiztitle': currentquiz}).quizquestions[currentQuestion]
 },

 length: function (){
     questionlength = $(Quizzes.findOne({'quiztitle': currentquiz}).quizquestions).length;
     return questionlength;
 },

 answers: function(){
     currentquiz = this.quiztitle;
     currentQuestion = Session.get('currentQuestion') || 0;
     return Quizzes.findOne({'quiztitle': currentquiz}).answers[1][currentQuestion]
 }

});
```

As you can see some of this code is already duplicate (currentquiz = this.quiztitle). **How can I share currentquiz between functions within a helper?**

This is becoming a real problem as I need to define the variable currentquiz one time

```
 currentQuestion = [0,0,0,0,0];
```

But current code resets the currentquestion any time I activate the helper in the template. I can;t define it above the function $(document.ready) wrap to set the variable or define it . This should be really easy right?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? the two helpers could be called with different contexts (different `this`s). And I'm assuming you wouldn't just want to use a global variable? Are you perhaps thinking of a common sub-function, rather than a shared variable?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should be using a sub-function or shared variable. Function within the helper will indeed be called by different contexts. It just seems redundant to be defining variables that have the same value in the same context several times in a helper.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old thread but I just came across the same problem. What you can do is define a reactive variable on the template level:

```
var abc;
Template.XY.rendered = function(){
  abc = new ReactiveVar("abc");
},

Template.XY.helpers({
  someFunction:function(){
  return abc.get();
}
)}
```

I define a `var abc;` to bind the variable to the template instance (i guess this can also be done with `this.abc = new ...` )

Comment: I think defining abc outside the scope can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a variable available in the template helpers and events you just need to add it in the template instance.

In the **onCreated** function you can access the template instance with the keyword **this**.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
    this.mySharedVariable = new ReactiveVar("myValue");
});
```

In the helpers you can access to the templace instance with **Template.instance()**.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    myHelper1(){
        const instance = Template.instance();
        instance.mySharedVariable.get(); // Get the value "myValue"
        // Do something
    },
    myHelper2(){
        const instance = Template.instance();
        instance.mySharedVariable.get(); // Get the value "myValue"
        // Do something
    }
});
```

In the events you can access to the template instance with the **second parameter** of the function.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click .js-do-something' : function(event, instance){
        instance.mySharedVariable.set("newValue");  // Set the value "newValue"
    }
});
```

In the example above i'm using a ReactiveVar so if its value get changed the two helpers **myHelper1** and **myHelper2** will re-execute. But be free to use normal variable depending on your need.

PS: Because **Session** are global, **you should not use Session** if you only use this "shared" variable inside your template.